# About passing table name as a parameter in mybatis

Tags: parameters, mybatis

When i try to pass a table name as parameter to the sql mapping, such as

```
public MatchResult get(long id, String tablename);
```

Mapper xml:

```
<select id="get" parameterType="long" resultType="myresult">
    select * from ${1} where id=#{0}
</select>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`${}` doesn't support the parameter index according to my test.** You can use `Param` annotation to specify the parameter name in your mapper API declaration.

```
public MatchResult get(long id, @Param("tablename") String tablename);
```

Mapper xml:

```
<select id="get" resultType="myresult">
    select * from ${tabelname} where id=#{0}
</select>
```

**An alternative is to use an object of your own class or a map as the parameter if you don't want the `IBatis/MyBatis` specific annotation `Param` in your mapper API declaration.**

Take the map as an example, your java API could be:

```
public MatchResult get(Map<String, Object> params);
```

The mapper xml statements could be:

```
<select id="get" parameterType="map" resultType="myresult">
    select * from ${tablename} where id=#{id}
</select>
```

And put the id and tablename to the map with the key "id" and "tablename", before invoking the API.

Comment: This helped me figure out that in my case, I needed to replace '#{' with '${':  The former is for MyBatis to create a 'PreparedStatement parameter', while the latter is for plain String injection.  See "String Substitution" section in http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Comment: ^ Very important point about the difference between ${...} and #{...} syntax.
One is SQL Injection safe (#) and the other NOT ($),