# Using Spring-Mybatis to get columns from an unknown table

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

So I am creating a project that allows users (trusted users) to run sql templates like INSERT, CREATE TABLE, SELECT, etc.. The problem is I do not know the table column and the user might do a SELECT statement.

The problem in spring is that it requires a "model" for a table which is a pre-written java class that has variables which is the same as the "unknown columns". Do I need to dynamically create java classes for each tables during CREATE TABLE statement? Or is there any other way to handle this problem?

Example:
(? is a wild card)

Table column: ?_id, ?_name, ?_class...
Java Class:

```
public class ?{
    private int ?_id;
    private String ?_name;
    private String ?_class;
    ....
    //setter and getter
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: maybe you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666189/about-passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-mybatis

Comment: I just found the problem, the return Data Type should be List<Map> thanks for the help though!!

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=viakiba/karanotes/karanotes-master/src/main/java/haust/vk/dao/impl/PraiseDaoImpl.java#

this is the reference if you guys need help in this topic